# Redirect issue in mutlisite in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to integrate the multi site in word press .

My wp-config.php :-

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost.com/escort');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost.com/escort');
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
// define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
define( 'PB_BACKUPBUDDY_MULTISITE_EXPERIMENT', true );
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost.com/escort');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://localhost/escort');




 My htaccess :- 
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /escart/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Its not working . I got the below error 
The page isn't redirecting properly . How can I fix this .

Comment: define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost.com');     define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/escort/');

Comment: Now I got  db connection issue Error establishing a database connection

Answer (score 1):

The DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE, NOBLOGREDIRECT constants should be a domain only. Instead use the PATH_CURRENT_SITE constant aswell

```
<?php
$base = '/escort/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/escort/');
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://localhost.com');
?>
```

Comment: Now I got  db connection issue Error establishing a database connection

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/escort/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

    ?>
```

Try This one htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Now I got  db connection issue Error establishing a database connection

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /escart/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: increase WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in config file.

Comment: Now I put the below code in wp-config.php define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );

Comment: I increased the memory limit  as 500M

Comment: Need to change the an y database details ?

Comment: i have updated htaccess code look at my answer and past htaccess code in you .htaccess file.

Comment: refer this URL also : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-page-isnt-redirecting-properly-41

Comment: Error establishing a database connection